# Safari asks for Flash to be enabled for every website?

Tags: safari, adobe-flash

I have gotten along quite well without Flash for a long time.  But recently I had reason to install it for one particular website.  Since it is installed, I figured I'd have it prompt me if another site wants Flash.  But I've been asked to enable it for **every** website, almost all of which have worked fine without it and work fine after I say "never for this website."

I've tried FireFox on a few of those sites, with no apparent difference from before.

Should I report it as a bug?  Can I put a stop to it, and if not, how do I remove Flash without breaking other things?

Comment: I don't have Flash any more, but Safari prefs > security > Plug-in Settings... ought to let you choose a default action for newly-visited sites, if you still need it for that one site.

Comment: Yes, the default action is Ask, like I selected.  But it shouldn't be asking when the site has no Flash.

Comment: so why don't you just set the default to 'off' ?

Comment: For the reason I said in the question—so that if Flash was needed, it would tell me.  Unfortunately, I didn't know that so many stupid sites ask for Flash when they DON'T need it.

Comment: One reason I no longer have Flash... adverts use it, adverts can be nasty, Flash can be [& has been] compromised. If I **must** use Flash I use Chrome [flash built-in] then quit after I've done what must be done.

Comment: But Chrome owes its allegiance to NSA's biggest competitor.  Not sure I like that trade-off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Safari Preferences, Security tab, and click Plug-In Settings. Select Flash Player on the left, and ensure that "when visiting other websites" is set to **Off**, rather than **Ask**.

[image]

Comment: I don't want it off.  If a site needs Flash, I _want_ it to ask.  It should not be asking for a site that doesn't need Flash.  Like it did a couple years ago on another Mac.

Comment: Oh,ok... your question said you'd installed it for one particular website, so I assumed that was the only one you cared about (I see you've clarified that now). In that case there's either something else weird going on, or all those websites really do have an optional Flash component for an ad or a tracker or something else you're not seeing. I just set that option to "Ask", browsed around to a bunch of different websites, and so far I haven't been asked once.

Comment: Hmm.  After reading your comment, I visited three sites on different domains that I maintain myself (but hadn't recently visited.  None of them asked for Flash.  So I guess there are a lot of sites that stupidly request Flash when they don't actually use it.   Grrr.  With a little extra detail, that makes your answer acceptable.